# Print css (with variables) to a file

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, file, service, render

I have a service that generates epubs, thus I need to generate a css file to be embedded in the epub.

I created a css view under `epub/style.css.erb` but since the logic is in the service and not in the controller, it seems there is no way to call [`render_to_string`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Base/render_to_string). Actually, the service is wrapped in a sidekiq job, which can be called also from an `after_update` from the model, so this is of further hindrance to [`render_to_string`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Base/render_to_string).

I could create like an `EpubController` and call the `render_to_string` method from there. But from my service, located under `app/services/epub_export.rb`, how do I send parameters to / receive output from the controller? This way it smells like I would break the MVC pattern.

But I also don't like the classical way, e.g.

```
File.open(@css_path, 'w') do |f|
  f.puts "@charset utf-8;"
  f.puts "/* Styles for GEPUB Sample Book */"
  f.puts "h1"
  f.puts "{"
  f.puts "  text-align: center;"
  f.puts "  color: #0000ff;"
  f.puts "  font-weight: normal;"
  f.puts "  font-family: #{@font_family};"
  f.puts "}"
end
```

Or is there an alternative to this?

Comment: What do you mean, "since the logic is in the service and not in the controller, it seems there is no way to call `render_to_string`"?

Comment: I have a service under `app/services/epub_export.rb` that does this, so there I cannot call `render_to_string`

Comment: Edited question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use `render_to_string` all the time in an asychronous job outside a controller to generate a pdf. That looks something like:

```
class FooService

  ...

  def pdf
    ActionController::Base.new.render_to_string(
      pdf:        "pdf_name", 
      template:   'path/to/template',
      locals:     {presenter: self},
      page_size:  'Letter',
      encoding:   "UTF-8",
      margin: {
        top: 20,
        bottom: 20
      }
    )
  end

  ...

end
```

Have you tried something along those lines?

Comment: Thanks, it works :) I will use this solution for now. Hope calling `ActionController` in a service is not so harmful... :)

Comment: It's (roughly) the way DHH does it, so you should be OK. You might want to check out [this thread](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/18409). BTW, which version of rails are you on? Something like this is now built into 5 (which I'm not on yet).

Comment: My Rails version is 5.0.7

Comment: Like I said, I'm not on 5 yet. But, you might take and look at [this article](https://coreyward.svbtle.com/render-template-in-a-poro-ruby-on-rails) and the [source code](https://github.com/brainopia/rails/blob/action_view_render/actionpack/test/controller/renderer_test.rb).